# How to put multiple selection functionality on datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to put multiple selection functionality on `datetimepicker`?
I managed to do the same thing on `datepicker` by just putting `multidate:true` but in this `datetimepicker` it does not work. I tried google and here on Stack Overflow but no luck so far.

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss',
  multidate: true,
  language: 'pt-BR'
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
              </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
</script>
```

Comment: How I know there is no build-in method for this usecase in jquery's datetimepicker. As solution you could setup 2 datetimepicker tables to narrow down the from-to date selection.

Comment: @lortschi what you are saying it is true because I have seen a question which was asked three years ago but no answer. You have opened my eyes